# Is it possible to drop tables using regular expressions instead of specyfing the string names individually? (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

I am using an oracle database. In the database I have I have a lot of tables. The names start with "temp_....": e.g. TEMP_EXP1, TEMP_EXP2, Is it possible to drop all of them at once with one query, e.g. by specifying a regular expression?

Comment: I believe you cannot do this in oracle, but if you have at your disposal some programming language that is able to execute queries on an oracle connection (e.g. python with cx_Connect; SAS odbc connection, etc.), then you can use that language to 1)get the list of tables and 2)parse each one in a drop statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can't drop table with a *query*. You must use `DROP TABLE xxxx` DDL.

But you can write  a query that produces the required `DROP`statements, such as

```
select 'DROP TABLE '||owner||'.'|| table_name||';' as ddl
from dba_tables where 
owner = 'xx' and
table_name <<< put here your REGEXP filter
```

Than copy the produced `DROP` statements and execute them in you IDE or SQL*Plus.

In case you have no access to the dictionary view `DBA_TABLES` and you drop the tables in a schema you are connected use this statement

```
select 'DROP TABLE '|| table_name||';' as ddl
from user_tables
where 
table_name <<< put here your REGEXP filter
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the idea, however  I do not have the priveleges to access the schema with all table names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some dynamic SQL to drop your tables; for example:

```
begin
    for i in 1..3 loop
        execute immediate 'drop table TEMP_EXP' || i;
    end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the tables and drop it using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

`DBMS_OUTPUT` is added for displaying the name of the table being dropped. Be careful before running!

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
EXEC dbms_output.enable(NULL);

BEGIN
   FOR t IN (SELECT owner, table_name
               FROM all_tables
              WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (table_name, 'TEMP_EXP\d+')) --or any other REGEX that suits you.
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
         'DROPPING TABLE ' || t.owner || '.' || t.table_name);

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || t.owner || '.' || t.table_name;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the idea, however  I do not have the priveleges to access the schema with all table names.